# Understand parameters of tf.slice in tensorflow and why I cannot change it

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, slice

Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mp_image
filename = "abc.jpeg"
input_image = mp_image.imread(filename)
my_image=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None, None, 3])
myimage=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None, None, 3])
slice1=tf.slice(my_image,[0,100,0],[300,400,-1]) #[x,y,?],[x,y,?]
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(slice1,feed_dict={my_image: input_image})
print(result.shape)
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

In slice 1 what does the parameters passed as list indicate[x,y,?],[x,y,?].

In  tf.slice(image_tensor,[0,0,0],[100,200,-1]).What does 0 and -1 stands for here and why i cannot change them?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the docstring for [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice), the parameters are `input_`, `begin` and `size` respectively. Your code is doing

```
slice1=tf.slice(my_image,[x_begin,y_begin,channel_begin],[x_size,y_size,channel_size])
```

Note that the third parameter describes the `size` and not the absolute `to` index (@XMANX is mistaken). The `size` parameter accepts a sentinel value of -1, which means that all remaining elements in the dimension are included in the slice.

For example, if you had a tensor `t` with shape `[X, Y, Z]`

```
tf.slice(t, [x_begin, y_begin, z_begin], [x_size, y_size, z_size])
```

is equivalent to doing

```
t[x_begin : x_begin+x_size, y_begin : y_begin+y_size, z_begin : z_begin+z_size]
```

In order to extract just the R channel from an image, you would do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mp_image

filename = "abc.jpeg"
input_image = mp_image.imread(filename)
my_image=tf.placeholder("uint8",[None, None, 3])
# Doesn't slice along the x and y dimensions, but takes only one channel
sliced = tf.slice(my_image,[0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, 1])
squeezed = tf.squeeze(slice)  # Removes last dimension
with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(squeezed,feed_dict={my_image: input_image})
plt.imshow(result)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I gives an error on 'plt.imshow(result)'||**TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data**||... can it really print just R channel. Please provide me complete code snippet that does print only one channel. @rachelim

Comment: When you get an error like that, you should check what shape input `plt.imshow` expects by reading its docstring... If you do that, you'll see that it expects the input to have the shape (n, m) or (n, m, 3) or (n, m, 4).

In this case, you're trying to give it an (n, m, 1) image. You can remove the last dimension (to create a (n,m) image) by doing tf.squeeze. I've edited the code snippet above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

`[x,y,?],[x,y,?]` in your case, the third parameter of the shape is a number of image channels

For answer on a second question lets take a look how `tf.slice` working, in case of the image with RGB channels it looks like `tf.slice([from_x, from_y, from_channel], [to_x, to_y, to_channel])` also in shape definition you can use `-1` this way you telling sensor flow slice to maximum available value. From your code sample you trying a slice input image `[0,100, 0],[300,400, 3]`, you can change the third param and it is a valid code, but should remember [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) allows you to show pictures only `(M, N), (M, N, 3), (M, N, 4)`

Code explanation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mp_image

filename = "abc.png"
input_image = mp_image.imread(filename)
my_image = tf.placeholder("float32",[None, None, 3])
myimage = tf.placeholder("float32",[None, None, 3])

# this way you slicing RGB image
slice1=tf.slice(my_image,[0,100,0],[300, 400, -1])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(slice1, feed_dict={my_image: input_image})

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(result)

# this way you slicing image and keep just R channel
slice1=tf.slice(my_image,[0,100,0],[300, 400, 1]) #[x,y,?],[x,y,?]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    result = sess.run(slice1, feed_dict={my_image: input_image})

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
# matplotlib imshow show need extra options to render image with single chanel
plt.imshow(np.reshape(result, (result.shape[0], result.shape[1])), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOuSw.png)

Comment: Can I change the values of from_channel and to_channel? If yes, what can be the possible values of it and what difference will it yield in the output?

Comment: You can change this value, for example `tf.slice([0, 0, 0], [-1, -1, 1])` slice input image and keep just `R` chanel.

Comment: Thanks for your effort but still I am not able to get the image's R channel using your code. Should I use different library like bokeh. I am new to tensorflow. Please provide me full code snippet that will show any 1 channel.